# Kth element formed by joining N array sorted element in ascending order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

You are given a string S of length N. The string S consist of digits from 1-9. Consider the string indexing to be 1-based.
You need to divide the string into blocks such that the i<sup>th</sup> block contains the elements from the index((i-1) * X + 1) to min(N,(i * X) (both inclusive). A number is **valid** if it is formed by choosing exactly one digit from each block and placing the digits in the order of their block number.

For example :

If the given string is '123456789' and X = 3, the blocks formed are [123],[456],[789]. Few valid number are 146,159,348 etc. but 124 and 396 are invalid.

Among all the **valid numbers** that can be formed,I have to determine the **K<sup>th</sup>** number if all the **unique valid numbers** are sorted in ascending order.

My idea was to sort each block and then figure out which number will be the **K<sup>th</sup>** number.
But I got stuck on how to mathematically or any other approach for  find **K<sup>th</sup>** element.

```
def getK(N:int, X:int, K:int, S:str):
    from math import ceil
    i = 1
    N = len(S)
    S = list(S)
    while i <= ceil(N / X):
        start = (i - 1) * X
        end = min(N, i * X) - 1
        S[start:end+1] = sorted(S[start:end+1])
        print(S[start:end+1])
        i += 1
    print(S)
```

Please help me finding out way how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, divide the string into blocks:

```
132 | 444 | 675 | 89
```

Note the the last block may have fewer than *X* digits*. Also note that whichever digit you pick from the second block, it's always a 4. Sort the blocks and weed out the duplicates**:

```
123 | 4 | 567 | 89
```

Now, when you enumerate the possible numbers in order:

```
1458
1459
1468
1469
1478
1479
2458
...
```

you can observe a pattern:

- The last digit changes with a frequency of 1, that is: each turn.
- The second but last digit changes with a frequency of 2, which is the "cycle length" of the last block.
- The third but last digit changes would a frequency of 6 if there were any other digits to change to. Six is the cycle length of the last two blocks combined.
- The first digit changes with a frequency of 6, which is the combined cycle length of the last three blocks.

So, count the lengths of the unique blocks:

```
3 | 1 | 3 | 2
```

For each block, find the products of the counts from that block to the end:

```
18 | 6 | 6 | 2
```

The first number is the total number of combinations, *N*. If *k* > *N*, signal failure. (Return `None` or raise an exceptuon.) Otherwise, pop it off the array and add a 1 at the end. Now you have the "update frequencies" for each digit:

```
6 | 6 | 2 | 1
```

Now, make *k* a zero-based index, *K* = *k* − 1, because it makes the calculations easier. Say that *K* = 8:

- The first digit changes with every 6th number. *K* div 6 = 1, which is the zero-based index of the number to pick from the first block: "2". Take the remainder of that division: *K* ← *K* mod 6.
- The second digit also changes with every 6th digit. *K* div 6 = 0: pick the digit at index 0. (There is only on digit here anyway, "4".) The remainder is 2.
- The third digit changes with every 2nd digit: *K* div 2 = 1: pick the digit at index 1: "6". The remander is 0.
- The last digit always changes with every digit. Take the digit at index *K* = 0: "8"

What's the number? 2468!

__________
* You don't need `ceil` from the `math` mosule. You can split your string `s` easily with `range`, which also takes care of incomplete end blocks:

```
blocks = [s[i:i + X] for i in range(0, n, X)]
```

** You can remove duplicate entries with a `set`:

```
digits = [sorted(set(i)) for i in blocks]
```

***  Here, div means integer division and mod means modulo. The respective Python operators are `//` and `%`: `p == (p // q) * q + p % q.`

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@M Oem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829847/kth-element-formed-by-joining-n-array-sorted-element-in-ascending-order/66830373#66830373) here is my code for above problem.

```
def Find_It(N, X, K, S):
    S = list(S)
    blocks = [S[i:i + X] for i in range(0, N, X)]
    digits = [sorted(set(i)) for i in blocks]
    freq = [len(x) for x in digits]
    for i in range(len(freq) - 2, -1, -1):
        freq[i] = freq[i] * freq[i + 1]
    if K > freq[0]:
        return -1
    freq.append(1)
    ans = []
    K = K - 1
    for i in range(1, len(freq)):
        div = K // freq[i]
        ans.append(digits[i - 1][div])
        K = K % freq[i]
    print(''.join(ans))


Find_It(11, 3, 9, '13244467589')
Find_It(10, 5, 10, '1234567891')
Output: 2468,29
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@M Oem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) approach here is my code for above problem in C++

```
void solve(string s, int n, int x, int k) {
    vector<string>v;
    int idx = 1;
    string temp = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i < min(n, idx*x)) {
            temp.push_back(s[i-1]);
        }
        else {
            temp.push_back(s[i-1]);
            sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
            // cout << temp << " ";
            v.push_back(temp);
            temp = "";
            idx++;
        }
    }

    int m = v.size();
    int arr[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = v[i].length();
    }

    for (int i = m-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i+1];
        // cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    int last = arr[m-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] / last;
        // cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    string ans = "";
    k = k-1; //convert to based 0 index
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int t = k / arr[i];
        string curr = v[i];
        ans.push_back(curr[t]);
        k = k % arr[i];
        // cout << ans << " ";
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}

//solve("132456978", 9, 3, 6);
//O/p: 159
```